# How can I take a screenshot of a window without the background?

Tags: release-freya, screenshot

When I take a window screenshot, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: I've used [screencloud](https://screencloud.net/) in the past and liked it a lot. You might want to give it a try :) It's [open source](https://github.com/olav-st/screencloud) and the maintainer was pretty responsive when I had questions and suggestions.

Comment: Ok, I will. I hadn't tried it with elementary yet, so I couldn't in good conscience offer it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [ScreenCloud](https://screencloud.net/) in the past and liked it a lot. It's [open source](https://github.com/olav-st/screencloud) and the maintainer was pretty responsive when I had questions and suggestions.

And it's pretty versatile, too. Its features include:

- 3 shortcuts which take a screenshot of different areas areas (full screen, a specific window, or an area you select by dragging a rectangle)
- customizable keyboard shortcuts
- several choices of target location for the images (including cloud services like Dropbox and Imgur).
- customizable filenames for the screenshots, which accepts date/time arguments (for example, `%Y-%m-%d %T` produces `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`).
- an option whether to just take a screenshot immediately with the default settings, or to show a GUI popup asking you to confirm the settings every time

Answering your specific question, it can also either include or exclude the window borders. On elementary, the shadows will always be taken in the screenshot (see below). However, with and without borders will control *where* the border is - so it will either just be the window you want, then a white background added and then a shadow, or it will be the thing that is actually behind the window, including shadows. Bit complex, look at these pictures, with and without borders:

[image]
[image]

Download a `.deb` at their homepage - click **Download at the top menu**.

Comment: @Tim thanks for editing the question and greatly improving it. I organized it some more, but the final part, with the images, is a little confusing to me, since both images show the shadow, but you wrote "it can (...) exclude the window borders, which means you won't get the shadow"

Comment: Does it actually have a "with/without borders" setting, or is that a window screenshot vs. custom area screenshot? From the images it seems you're doing the latter.

Comment: I don't understand why the background appears in the first image and not in the second, unless you chose different areas to capture. Are you taking both screenshots using the same shortcut?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25497/discussion-between-waldyrious-and-tim).

Answer (score 12):

You can make beautiful screenshots of windows with shadow using [screenshot-tool](https://launchpad.net/screenshot-tool).

Add this PPA and install package:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenshot-tool
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

Example:
[image]

Supported only GTK3+ apps.

Comment: After installation, two 'Screenshot' entries will be displayed when searching in a launcher, because each application (the default `gnome-screenshot` and the installed above `screenshot`) has in `usr/share/applications` a `.desktop` file that contains the same line `Name=Screenshot`. Gnome Screenshot has a desktop file called `gnome-screenshot.desktop`. Unless you want to remove `gnome-screenshot` altogether, open it as administrator and change the 'Name' line under [Desktop Entry] to `Name=Gnome Screenshot`

Answer (score 1):

[Screencloud](https://screencloud.net) and [screenshots-tools](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Screenshot) is equally as good. Picture with a smooth-shadow-border will be obtained perfectly.

Here for example, the first images obtained with Screencloud
and a second image obtained with Screenshot-tool
[image: Screencloud do]

[image: Screenshot-tool do]

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of these solutions :

1. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> *instead* of <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> button (using your keyboard)

   or
2. Use an application like **Shutter** or the default screenshot application

Comment: Well, Shutter works pretty well! You can follow this tutorial [How to take screenshots with Shutter](http://www.compureboot.com/tutorials.php?id=16)

Comment: It's dosen't, you can select and capture only the selected window

Comment: Well, i'm using Shutter right now. When you open the application, click on the indicator icon and choose the type of screenshot you want to take. In your case, you have to chose window under cursor. You will have to hover the window you want to capture and wait for a few seconds

Comment: This is a screenshot of what i'm talking about [OmgUbuntu Shutter](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/shutter.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe what you want is to able make screenshot of selected area?

If you do, then you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScrn</kbd>, and your cursor will change to make selection, select your desired area, and release your click/mouse, then your image will be saved to your clipboard!

Or, Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> to save your selection.

This is the full list of keyboard shortcuts for screenshot.

[image: Keyboard Shortcut For Screenshot]