# Name of default screenshot tool in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, screenshot

After reading [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-window-without-the-background), I attempted to launch the default screenshot tool via the terminal (for debugging) but I couldn't find out what the name was.

I tried with `screen*` but nothing came up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command ran by clicking the screenshot application's icon is `gnome-screenshot --interactive` ([Source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/gnome-screenshot-freya/view/head:/src/gnome-screenshot.desktop.in#L5)).