# How can I remove default "Screenshot" app from Freya

Tags: release-freya

I want to remove default Screenshot App from Freya. How can I remove it.

Comment: Just curious: why?

Comment: never mind: Please search before posting _simple_ questions. The name of the app is : `gnome-screenshot`  see [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/139/name-of-default-screenshot-tool-in-freya). Now open Software Center and remove :)

Comment: I dont need after moving to another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default name of the app is : `gnome-screenshot`

Open software center and remove it.

If you want to use terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screenshot
```

Comment: it worked. and i removed the default Screenshot app.